# Unable to restart kernel in spyder after changing the enviroment

Tags: python, kernel, spyder

I created a new environment to download packages.
When I try to restart the kernel after changing the environment, I am not able to restart the kernel, and I get this :

```
Restarting kernel...  

The following argument was not expected: C:/Users/MyName/Miniconda3/envs/spyder-env  Run with --help for more information.

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\MyName\Miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Users\MyName\Miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in
_run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from spyder_kernels.console import start   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 21, in <module>
    import ipykernel   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .connect import *  # noqa   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\ipykernel\connect.py", line 11, in <module>
    import jupyter_client   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .asynchronous import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\jupyter_client\asynchronous\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\jupyter_client\asynchronous\client.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.channels import HBChannel   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\jupyter_client\channels.py", line 12, in <module>
    import zmq.asyncio   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\zmq\__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    from zmq import backend   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    raise original_error from None   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\zmq\backend\select.py", line 31, in select_backend
    mod = import_module(name)   File "C:\Users\MyName\Miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "C:\Program Files\pkgs\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import ( ImportError: cannot import name '_device' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Program Files\pkgs\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)


Restarting kernel...   The following argument was not expected: C:/Users/Marie/Miniconda3/envs/spyder-env Run with --help for more information.
```